# File upload form with file resolution check/validation

Tags: magento2, form-validation, file-upload

Our products come with an optional personalised printing service. Customers can choose to print a logo on a shirt. Therefore we need a form with a logo upload function.

Which Requires file extension validation and resolution check.

Does anybody have experience with available form builders for Magento with such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Refer Below link:

> https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/best-magento-t-shirt-designer-extensions-and-tools.html

There are lots of extension development companies in the market, who provide this kind of extension.

Comment: These are complete tools integrated in productpage. I just need a form builder with upload filecheck (Resolution and filetype)